# Zero set of convolution of integrable function and compactly supported smooth function.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $Z_f$ be the zero set of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $S_g$ be the support of $g\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$ What can we say about the zero set of their convolution $(f*g)$?

$$(f*g)(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_\mathbb{R}g(x-y)f(y)dy$$

Comment: We can say it's the set where $f*g = 0$. What would you like to say about it? What are your thoughts on the matter? Where are you having trouble figuring this out?

Comment: Can we explicitly find $Z_{f*g}$ in terms of $Z_f$ and $S_g$ @Paul Sinclair ?

Comment: I got that $$Z_{f*g}^\circ \supseteq \left(\overline{\overline{Z_f^c}+S_g}\right)^c.$$ Can we get in terms of equality?

Comment: What I want to know is how convolution with a compactly supported smooth function effect to the vanishing set of a integrable function? For example if $f$ vanishes on a positive measure set then after convolving with a compactly supported function, will the vanishing set of their convolution remain positive measure?